Error when build AOSP 14 - internal error: undefined variable CTS_TEST_SUITES_DEFAULT
Details of the Issue with Building AOSP 14
Problem Description
When attempting to build AOSP 14, I encountered an error during the build process. The build environment was configured according to the requirements for AOSP 14, but I encountered the following error:
internal error: undefined variable CTS_TEST_SUITES_DEFAULT
11:02:32 fatal errors encountered

#### failed to build some targets (02:25 (mm:ss)) ####

Steps Taken

Environment Setup:

Executed source build/envsetup.sh.
Selected the build environment with the command lunch aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug.


Build Information:

PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=VanillaIceCream
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_cf_x86_64_phone
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.4.0-150-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-18.04.6-LTS
BUILD_ID=MAIN


Memory Warning:

My machine has 16 GB of RAM.



Errors Encountered

Error: internal error: undefined variable CTS_TEST_SUITES_DEFAULT
Details: Build failed due to fatal errors.

Full Terminal
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:/media/thanhchung/data/AOSP14$ source build/envsetup.sh
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:/media/thanhchung/data/AOSP14$ lunch aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=VanillaIceCream
PLATFORM_VERSION=VanillaIceCream
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_cf_x86_64_phone
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=silvermont
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=silvermont
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.4.0-150-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-18.04.6-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
BUILD_ID=MAIN
OUT_DIR=out
============================================

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Wondering whether to use user, userdebug or eng?

  user        The builds that ship to users. Reduced debugability.
  userdebug   High fidelity to user builds but with some debugging options
              enabled. Best suited for performance testing or day-to-day use
              with debugging enabled.
  eng         More debugging options enabled and faster build times, but
              runtime performance tradeoffs. Best suited for day-to-day
              local development when not doing performance testing.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

thanhchung@Chung-Computer:/media/thanhchung/data/AOSP14$ echo "$TARGET_PRODUCT-$TARGET_RELEASE-$TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT"
aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:/media/thanhchung/data/AOSP14$ m 
11:00:10 ************************************************************
11:00:10 You are building on a machine with 15.6GB of RAM
11:00:10 
11:00:10 The minimum required amount of free memory is around 16GB,
11:00:10 and even with that, some configurations may not work.
11:00:10 
11:00:10 If you run into segfaults or other errors, try reducing your
11:00:10 -j value.
11:00:10 ************************************************************
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=VanillaIceCream
PLATFORM_VERSION=VanillaIceCream
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_cf_x86_64_phone
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=silvermont
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=silvermont
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.4.0-150-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-18.04.6-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
BUILD_ID=MAIN
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
internal error: undefined variable CTS_TEST_SUITES_DEFAULT
11:02:32 fatal errors encountered

#### failed to build some targets (02:25 (mm:ss)) ####

thanhchung@Chung-Computer:/media/thanhchung/data/AOSP14$ 

Has anyone encountered the same error and can you suggest to me how to fix it?

The error looks explicit - you need at least 64GB of RAM to build AOSP AOSP Build Requirements

I found the solution. The error was caused by insufficient memory (16GB RAM is insufficient). To fix this error, I created a 34GB swap file on my SSD and now everything works fine. Thanks for your advice. I have posted the solution below. @Vitaliy

@ChunhThanhDe yes this what I suggested, why not accept my answer? :)

Thank you, sorry for my delay xD. you deserve it
